# List exercise - Return the number of strings based on a condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm a newbie in the Python world. I'm still struggling with some of the basic concepts of Python.

Question: **Write a program that counts the number of string from a given list of strings. This string is 2 characters or more and the first and last characters are the same **

As the question mentioned in the title, this was my approach:

```
def string_num(items): 
    for a in items: 
        len(a) >= 3 and (a[0] == a[-1]) 
    return items.count(a) 
print(string_num(['abc','xyz','aba','1221']))
```

I assumed that the `.count()` function cannot be used here to count string in a list under a specific condition. I have been looking around but I still have not seen any explanation. Could someone help me explain what's wrong with this code, or what the `.count()` function does exactly that it cannot be used here?

Appreciate all the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.count()` function counts the occurences of a value in an array, see the example [here](https://www.educative.io/answers/what-is-the-array-count-function-in-python). If you want to get the number of elements in a list, use the `len()` function you already used for the string length.

Also, this will not work, since you don't actually count the number of strings that fulfill this condition.

I would do something like this:

```py
def string_num(items):
    item_count = 0
    for a in items: 
        if len(a) >= 3 and a[0] == a[-1]:
            item_count += 1
 
    return item_count
 
print(string_num(['abc','xyz','aba','1221']))
```

Or you could do it with [list comprehension](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp) like this, which is a bit more concise:

```
def string_num(items):
    return len([v for v in items if len(v) >= 3 and v[0] == v[-1]])

print(string_num(['abc','xyz','aba','1221']))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your mental model seems to be pretty far off from how Python actually works.

The `for` loop simply loops over an expression which ... does nothing. (It produces `True` or `False` in each iteration, but you don't do anything with that value.)

Finally, `items.count(a)` counts how many times `a` (which will be the value of `a` from the last iteration in the loop, which is still available after the loop has finished, i.e. `'1221'`) occurs in `items`.

I guess you were looking for something like

```
def string_num(items): 
    return len([a for a in items if len(a) >= 3 and a[0] == a[-1]])
```

which can be written less succinctly as

```
def string_num(items): 
    count = 0
    for a in items:
        if len(a) >= 3 and a[0] == a[-1]:
            count += 1
    return count
```

As remarked by Unmitigated, you could even use `sum` here, since `True` is numerically equal to 1 and `False` is 0.

```
def string_num(items): 
    return sum(len(a) >= 3 and a[0] == a[-1] for a in items)
```

Comment: It's not necessary to create a list to count the matching items: `return sum(len(a) >= 3 and a[0] == a[-1] for a in items)`